# Access to unnamed array in Array.forEach

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

Is there any way to access the target object's length property when using the forEach loop over an unnamed array?

```
# I'd like to be able to do something like:
[1, 2, 3].forEach (n, i) -> console.log n is < (arr.length - 1)
```

Comment: Well, it's a constant array, so you _know_ the length. In this example, it's 3. What do you need it for?

Comment: @daniel kullmann, the question also applies for code like `getSomething().forEach ...`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The callback of [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/array/foreach) takes tree arguments: value, index, **and the array being traversed**.

So you can do that:

```
[1, 2, 3].forEach (n, i, thearray) -> console.log n is < (thearray.length - 1)
```

Javascript:

```
[1, 2, 3].forEach(function(n, i, thearray) {
    console.log(n < thearray.length - 1);
});
```

Comment: Note to self,

[RTFM!](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/array/foreach)